# Adding in a function to my xml call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading off an xml file with the following script:

```
var varReverse = false;

$(xmlData).find('localoffer').each(function(){
  // ....
});
```

Based on the variable varReverse being true or false how do I update the above so it dynamically changes the script as below:

```
var varReverse = true;

$(xmlData).find('localoffer').reverse().each(function(){
  // ...
});
```

I have already got the plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

To handle the reversing of the xml

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't dynamically update the script(?) but you can include a `if` statement so it can follow one of two paths based on the variable.

Comment: Thanks Andy I was thinking that was the case. I have a lot of script in between the .each function and would not like it duplicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var localoffer = $(xmlData).find('localoffer');
localoffer = varReverse ? localoffer.reverse() : localoffer;
localoffer.each(function(){
       // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I knew it was something as simple as this but I was getting mixed up with what should go in the localoffer variable

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` statement. If you have a lot of code you don't want to duplicate, put it in it's own function and call it in each case from the `each` method:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

var varReverse = true;

function doSomething (i, el) {
  console.log($(el).html())
}

if (varReverse) {
  $('.class').reverse().each(doSomething);    
} else {
  $('.class').each(doSomething);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdd2bgLg/1/)

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tested this on my page as the top comment seemed the simplest and worked perfectly.